# NumPy setup / import issue in lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda

Runtime python 3.7 w/ compatible runtime 3.7

I keep getting Import error when trying to test API in lambda function

```
PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.7\"\n  * The NumPy version is: \"1.21.5\"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
```

I have tried adding numpy pip install inside docker, yet the issue still persists...

The dockfile engine used is amazonlinux:2

Any way of solving this weird issue?

Comment: Lambda provides its own numpy layer. Why do you need your own and don't use the one provided?

Comment: @Marcin the issue persists without NumPy imports in dockfile; I was adding it into dockfile to test changes

Comment: @marcin --ah I got it now; I was confused but understand lambda comes with some configured layers;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use Numpy layer [provided by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/).